# How did the Prussians work out what fraction of the population to recruit to the military?

Tags: military, prussia

Here's a quote from a teacher and author [John Taylor Gatto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Taylor_Gatto), which I found intriguing:

> The military which is quite an expensive institution to maintain even in times of peace is always constituted at the fraction of 1% to 1.5% of the entire adult male population.  Never heard that before?  That was a rule or principle worked out in Prussian Germany several hundred years ago.  Now your homework is to find out why that fraction.  I'll give you a clue:  the prison population of the United States is very close to the military population in the United States and that fraction too was worked out in Prussian Germany about two-hundred years ago.

Now, I'm not sure of the historical validity of this, nor could I find references to any such percentage... Anyone know if this can be verified?

I specifically want to know if the ruling class of Prussian Germany wanted to keep the military "always constituted at the fraction of 1% to 1.5% of the entire adult male population" and why this was significant (Why not 0.5%, or 2%?). Gatto died last year so there is no way to ask him directly for his source.

Comment: Start with Clausewitz (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_von_Clausewitz#Theory_of_war), who was instrumental in the rebuilding of the  Prussian Army after the disasters of 1806, and in the development of a theoretical foundation of training for the Prussian General Staff between 1815 and 1830.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - Thanks! It seems like he would be the kind of person this idea would come from, but I've yet to find references to this special "percentage". I've searched "percent" and "percentage" as terms, but I'm wondering if the usage is actually a whole number of troops juxtaposed to the number of the population.

Comment: You might have to search for translations of Albrecht von Boguslawski then.

Comment: On reflection, if the calculation was in fact "*several hundred years ago*" that probably refers to either Frederick II or his father Frederick William I. The latter built the Prussian Army army, the former gave it the Prussian state as revenue source. ;-)

Comment: If, however, the "*several hundred years ago*" is a slight exaggeration, then Gerhard von Scharnhorst may have been the responsible individual. It was he who was actually in charge of establishing the principles upon which Prussian Universal Service was established in the mid-19th Century. He was Clausewitz's mentor and teacher at various times.

Comment: What is the question?  I've tried to edit, but it isn't clear what you want to know.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace - I want to know if the ruling class of Prussian Germany wanted to keep the military "always constituted at the fraction of 1% to 1.5% of the entire adult male population".  Gatto died last year so there is no way to ask him directly for his source.

Comment: Where does the quote come from? It's not on the linked WP page and googling it has only hits for *this site!*

Comment: @LangLangC the quote is from a video interview he did several years ago. I posted this a while back and don’t recall which video.

Comment: That makes it so much harder to check the quote for accuracy and context… You seem to be the most likely candidate to re-find the quote. (I suspect that a few details point into a rather different direction than currently implied (and read into this by commentators) by the quote as is)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Have you been able to find this by now? – The "several hundred years" only *can* mean after Napoleon (~200), or when this other weapon came into the mix: *statistics*. Remember how shocked the Swedes were when they figured out how much of an effect their earlier war expenditures in terms of 'males lost' were compared to real life demographics, having vastly overestimated their very own population base…

Comment: @LangLangC: Perhaps the Swedes were just over confident: "*Brandenburg-Prussia in 1683 began to count its rural population. The first systematic population survey on the European continent was taken in 1719 in the Mark Brandenburg of the Kingdom of Prussia, in order to prepare the first general census of 1725.*" [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Census_in_Germany#Early_history)

Comment: @LangLangC - here we go, check the eighth paragraph on this page: https://www.johntaylorgatto.com/category/uncategorized/  "comprising a formulaic 1 percent of the population"